# How to dynamically find a USB device path?

Tags: linux, bash, gps, raspberry-pi4

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 connected to a SIM7600 Waveshare modem. The SIM7600 creates 4 virtual USB ports. One of these virtual ports is used for GPS and another is used for the actual modem.

Unfortunately, sometimes the GPS device is either on /dev/ttyUSB1 or /dev/ttyUSB2 while the modem seems to be either on /dev/ttyUSB3 or /dev/ttyUSB4.

Using the gpsd-clients package, I need to alter the file /etc/default/gpsd and add in the GPS device in this line:

```
# Device gpsd should collect to at boot time.
# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.
DEVICES="/device/path/to/gps"
```

I have a small bash script that gets a quick reading from the GPS device so I can get the latitude and longitude. However, sometimes it won't work after a reboot because the GPS virtual port has changed.

```
#!/bin/bash
gpspipe -w -n 10 | grep -m 1 lon
```

The lsusb command only yields one result for the SIM7600 modem and all the (virtual) USB ports are created with the same serial number, making it hard to differentiate between the virtual ports - which one is GPS or the modem?

Is there a way I can dynamically find the device path for the GPS? Perhaps using a bash script or writing a udev rule.

Results from lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port / Mobile Action MA-8910P
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory

# this is the modem
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1e0e:9001 Qualcomm / Option SimTech, Incorporated 

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro XM102K Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
/dev/input/event1 - SIGMACHIP_USB_Keyboard
/dev/input/event3 - SIGMACHIP_USB_Keyboard
/dev/input/event2 - SIGMACHIP_USB_Keyboard
/dev/input/mouse0 - SIGMACHIP_Usb_Mouse
/dev/input/event0 - SIGMACHIP_Usb_Mouse
/dev/ttyUSB0 - Prolific_Technology_Inc._USB-Serial_Controller_D

# these are the modem usb virtual ports
/dev/ttyUSB1 - SimTech__Incorporated_SimTech__Incorporated_0123456789ABCDEF
/dev/ttyUSB4 - SimTech__Incorporated_SimTech__Incorporated_0123456789ABCDEF
/dev/ttyUSB2 - SimTech__Incorporated_SimTech__Incorporated_0123456789ABCDEF
/dev/ttyUSB5 - SimTech__Incorporated_SimTech__Incorporated_0123456789ABCDEF
/dev/ttyUSB3 - SimTech__Incorporated_SimTech__Incorporated_0123456789ABCDEF
```